# Django ManyToMany field - access fields of through table

Tags: python, django, orm, m2m

Say I have the following model:

```
class User(Model):
    username = CharField(...)

class Project(Model):
    project_name = CharField(...)
    workers = ManyToManyField(User, through="ProjectAssignment")

class ProjectAssignment(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    project = ForeignKey(Project)
    role = CharField(...)  # name of the role a user has on a project
```

How to make query that gets the users who have role `Developer` on a project named `XY`? I could not find an example in Django documentation.

Comment: I have no idea what this has in common with my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should query via the through model itself.

```
developers = User.objects.filter(projectassignment__role='Developer', projectassignment__project=my_project)
```